# Power Query Editor - Convert Table to Text

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I m trying to format a column to text but i receive an error that i can not convert table to text.
I have noticed that some column values mention the word `Table` as the image shows:

[image]

Using the below formula a try to get the value store in the table but i accidentally create a `Record`.

`if [Decription] is table then [Decription]{0}  else  [Decription]`

Click on the Record a get the below:

How i can get the value of the record directly?

Thanks for the help.

[image]

*****UPDATES*****

```
  #"Removed Columns4" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Amount", "Type", "Currency"}),
  #"Transposed Table" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns4", {{"Decription", each if Value.Is(_, type table) then _ else #table({"Item"}, {{_}} ) }} ),
  #"ColumnsToExpand" = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(Transform, "Decription"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
  #"Expanded" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Transform, "Decription", ColumnsToExpand, ColumnsToExpand)
  in #"Expanded"`
```

**Error**

`Expression.Error: The import Transform matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?`

Answer (score 0):

if your data looks similar to

[image]

then you can use

```
#"PriorStepNameHere" = ... ,
Transform=Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepNameHere", {{"Description", each if Value.Is(_, type table) then _ else #table({"Item"}, {{_}} ) }} ),
ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(Transform, "Description"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Transform, "Description", ColumnsToExpand, ColumnsToExpand)
in Expanded
```

Comment: thanks for the quick respond. However, implimanting your solution i get another error. Have a look at the editted quetion.

Comment: You do not have a step named Transform.  You seem to have used the name #"Transposed Table" so you must use Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Transposed Table"